# How to combine 2 arrays based on same value of same key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge/combine 2 arrays based on the same key/value pair.

To be more clear, what I'm searching for is kind of a join function known in MySQL. The first array should be "joined" by the second one, based on the ID, which is the key/value pair 'name'.

How can I do this?

**1. ARRAY**

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => first
            [logo] => url
            [cat] => abc
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [name] => second
            [logo] => url
            [cat] => abc
        )
```

**2. ARRAY**

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => first
            [menu] => true
            [key] => value
        )
```

**NEW ARRAY (Expexted Result):**

```
[0] => Array
       (
           [name] => first
           [logo] => url
           [cat] => abc
           [menu] => true
           [key] => value
       )
```

As you an see, it's quite self-explaining. In this case, the 'name' key is like an ID (for both arrays).

Comment: to be more clear: what i'm searching for is kind of a join function known in MySQL..the first array should be "joined" by the second one, based on the ID, which is the key/value pair 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reindex your second array by name first, it will be easier to get those values from it.

```
$second = array_column($second, null, 'name');
```

(It's okay to do this if 'name' is unique in the array. I assume that's the case since you said it's "like an ID". If 'name' isn't unique then you'll lose some rows when you reindex, because array keys have to be unique.)

Then iterate your first array and merge any corresponding values in the second array into the result.

```
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($second[$value['name']])) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $second[$value['name']]);
    }
}
```

This would be like an inner join in SQL, where the result would only include rows where the value exists in both tables. If you wanted it to work more like a left join, then you'd need to merge a set of empty values for the keys in the second array if a matching name value wasn't found there.

```
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($second[$value['name']])) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $second[$value['name']]);
    } else {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, ['menu' => null, 'key' => null]);
    }
}
```

[Working example at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/BImoP)

Comment: thanks, but some values get lost, like 'logo', also, "It looks like you wanted the result to only contain names that existed in both arrays"...no, thats not what i want. Basicly, the first array is important, the second should only add additional key/values.

Comment: @Dave18 updated the answer. I added a link to a executable example. Just let me know if I'm still not understanding it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mergedArray = array_merge_recursive ($firstArray,$secondArray);

$newArray = [];
foreach( $mergedArray as $subArr ) {
    $newArray = array_merge($subArr,$newArray);
}
```